# replace string in LONGTEXT MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update some images in a new DB. I have read to use this SQL query:

```
UPDATE blogs SET body = REPLACE(body, 'http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://NEWSITE.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/old-wordpress/');
```

but that does nothing.

I ran this query to just make sure it was finding what I needed

```
SELECT REPLACE(body, 'http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://NEWSITE.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/old-wordpress/') from blogs
```

and that returned all I needed. Am I missing something in the `UPDATE`?

Example data :

in an `blogs` entry within `body`

```
<a href="http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/beforeandaftercollage2.jpeg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-9089" alt="beforeandaftercollage2" src="http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/beforeandaftercollage2-231x300.jpeg" width="231" height="300" /></a>
```

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ya, I cant see anything @Barmar. The first one returns 0 rows affected the second one returns 344 rows

Comment: Works here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2417a8/1

Comment: @Packy . . . The `SELECT` is going to return all the rows, even if the `replace()` does nothing.

Comment: The actual data is in `blogs` table `body` field which is `LONGTEXT`. All are parts of an image src value

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I added a chuck from from an entry to the question

Comment: have you tried to add where condition in your update query .. WHERE body LIKE '%http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/%'

Comment: @Mohammad no. What does that look like?

Comment: like this >>UPDATE blogs SET body = REPLACE(body, 'http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://NEWSITE.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/old-wordpress/')
WHERE body LIKE '%http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/%';

Comment: Still nothing. Not sure whats going on

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting the high water mark for the transaction log - that is the total amount of data of all before and after values exceeds the maximum allowed for a single transaction, especially since the datatype `LONGTEXT` suggests a lot of data.

Do the updates the chunks. Fortunately, MySQL has a very handy feature to do this:

```
UPDATE blogs SET
body = REPLACE(body, 'http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://NEWSITE.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/old-wordpress/')
WHERE body like '%www.OLDSITE.com%'
LIMIT 1000
```

The trick is `LIMIT 1000`, which stops the query after 1000 rows have been updated. You may need to tune the number `1000` down if the update still blows log size, or up for convenience.

You probably don't need the `WHERE` clause, but I don't have a MySQL instance handy to test it.

Comment: There's no error if the query fails because of this?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old topic but for those who may hit this problem, the problem is that in a `longtext` mysql field, the slashes are escaped by a backslash. So you have to either:

1. escape the slashes in the text (url), or
2. not change the slashes,

For example, write the code like below:

```
UPDATE blogs 
SET body = REPLACE(body,
    'http:\\/\\/www.OLDSITE.com\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/',
    'https:\\/\\/NEWSITE.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com\\/old-wordpress\/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql REPLACE func

```sql
# update sql
UPDATE blog set body=REPLACE(body, 'http://www.OLDSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://NEWSITE.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/old-wordpress/') where body LIKE '%/wp-content/uploads/"%'
```

```
REPLACE(string, from_string, new_string)
- string: Required, The original string
- form_string: Required, The substring to be replaced
- new_string: Required, The new replacement substring
```

link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp